# How to load a shader file synchronously in dart

Tags: dart, webgl, shader

I am developing a dart webgl application where i need to load shader codes from an external file. I could find that the remaining code runs before the shaders are loaded showing an error. Can someone help me out.

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow. Can you please improve your question. For example add some code that shows what you have tried and some information about what worked and what not. Maybe add some error message. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about loading shaders, but you can load assets asynchronously. Use Futures and HttpRequest:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  HttpRequest.getString(pathToShaderFile).then((shader) {
    // do something with the shader, which is a String
  });
}
```

The getString() method returns a Future, which is an object that contains a value "ready sometime in the future". In this case, the value (the contents of the HTTP request) is ready when the server responds with the shader file. When the value is ready, the `then()` callback is fired.

Here are the docs for HttpRequest.getString(): https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.HttpRequest#id_getString

Answer (score 1):

With WebGL based apps there is generally a need to load several resources to get the app set up: shader files, models, textures, world data etc. etc.

I believe what you want to do is load and process all of these resources *before* starting up the main animation loop and rendering frames.

To do this you want to arrange your resource loading and processing code to produce Futures, then use the static `Future.wait()` function to wait for each resource to be loaded and dealt with.

Here's a somewhat contrived example. Note that the futures that `wait()` waits on are those returned by the call to `then()` in `loadAndProcess()`, that is, the futures completed after the *processing* code executes rather than after 'HttpRequest.getString()' completes.

```dart
void main() {

  Future loadAndProcess(String file) {
    return HttpRequest.getString(file)
      .then((String s) {

        // Process resource content

      })
      .catchError((Error error) {

        // Deal with error

      });
  }

  Future.wait([loadAndProcess('a.txt'), loadAndProcess('b.txt'), loadAndProcess('c.txt')])
    .then((_) {

      // Go on with program ...

    });
}
```

The above assumes that loading and processing each resource is independent.

Also see the [Dart Library Tour: dart:async-Asynchronous Programming](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-asynchronous-programming)